# Invalid initializer : While assigning value from struct to a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Suppose I have two structs. One struct is a simple struct with a set of elements.

```
typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)) {
        float a1;
        float a2;
        uint32_t b1;
        uint32_t b2;
} item;
```

Other struct is simply an array of previous struct `item`.

```
typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)) {
        item item_queue[65000];
} item_arr;
```

What I need to do is to get an element from item_arr and assign it to an array of `item`s. I'm trying to achieve it in this way.

```
item_arr profile_arr[16] = {0};
```

After assigning values to profile_arr, I assigned an element from item_arr to new item array.

```
item temp_q[65000] = profile_arr[0].item_queue;
```

But This gives me **error: invalid initializer**.

Am I doing the initialization in a wrong way? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot initialize arrays by assignment. Also, the `__attribute__ ((packed))` is a sure signal of cargo culting - the structure is already packed and **were it not**, you'd just cause more harm by misaligning the members.

Comment: Thanks @AnttiHaapala . Then can you please suggest me a way to achieve this

Comment: Do you just want to copy  `profile_arr[0].item_queue` to `temp_q`?

Comment: Yes @P.W is there any other method to do that?

Comment: @Choxmi: Posted an answer. Check it out.

Comment: None of this makes any sense in the larger picture. But yes, you would use memcpy make a copy of an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to copy `profile_arr[0].item_queue` to `temp_q`, you can use [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy).

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );

memcpy(temp_q, profile_arr[0].item_queue, sizeof(temp_q));
```

Comment: Thanks @P.W . As an alternative this works perfect. Do you have any idea why my approach is unsuccessful? I'm just curious

Comment: In your assignment, `profile_arr[0].item_queue` is actually an address as `item_queue` itself is an array.

Comment: `profile_arr[0].item_queue` is type `item`. `item temp_q[65000]` is an *array of* type `item`. You cannot initialize an array with a single item without wrapping the value in braces, e.g. `{profile_arr[0].item_queue}` and then you are setting the 1st element of the array to `profile_arr[0].item_queue` and the remaining items `0`. To set all elements to that value, you must use `memcpy` (or a loop).

Comment: Thanks all. @DavidC.Rankin yes I used braces as well. But it didn't work. It seems `memcopy` or loop is the only solution. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin actually item_queue is an array

Comment: Oooh, you are right, `profile_arr[16]` is an *array of struct* containing an *array of* `item`... Good catch.